# Call a list value into a table on a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, datatable

I am trying to call a value from a List into a cell in a table on a different SharePoint page. The table is composed using html, and I think that is where I'm having trouble trying to connect the dots. The code for the particular cell is:

`<td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border-style:inset"> Business Days</td>`

The value in the List is a numeric value with I need displayed before the word Days in the cell. I have about 17 cells that I will need to set up, but if I can figure out one, I can work on the rest.

*ETA I'm thinking this would be a code snippet that I can insert in the  for that cell:

```
<td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font- 
weight:bold; border-style:inset"><div id="domesticshippingDays">   
</div>&nbspDays</td>
```

I'm at a loss how to get the value into the "domesticshippingDays" variable.

SharePoint 2013,
List name: CurrentTimeFrame,
Row 0 name: domesticshipping,
Row 1 name: overallshipping,
Column name: Days (internal name 'c3t9')

Thanks in advance for any help!

List preview:

[image]

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center" border="0">



<thead>
      <tr style="height:70px">
      <th rowspan="2" colspan="9" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; 
color:White; text-align:center; font-size:35pt; font-weight:bold; border- 
width:thick; border-style:inset">Current Time Frames<br> <span 
style="color:Red; font-size:25pt;">*second custom header*</span></th>
       </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

       <tr>
      <td colspan="9" style="font-size:5pt">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height:40px">
      <td colspan="4" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; color:White; 
text-align:left; font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold; border-width:thick; border- 
style:inset">Shipping</td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="4" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; color:White; 
text-align:left; font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold; border-width:thick; border- 
style:inset">Grading</td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; color:White; 
text-align:center; font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold; border-width:thick; 
border- 
style:inset">Domestic</td>
      <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font- 
weight:bold; border-style:inset"><div id="domesticShippingDays"></div></td>
      <td></td>


      <td colspan="3" style="width:30%; background-color:#015A78; color:White; 
text-align:center; font-size:20pt; font-weight:bold; border-width:thick; 
border- 
style:inset">Overall</td>

      <td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font- 
weight:bold; border-style:inset"><div id="canadaShippingDays"></div></td>
      </tr>

 </tbody>
</table> 




<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {


    var timeFrameRequestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + 
 "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('CurrentTimeFrame')/items";


    $.ajax({
        url: timeFrameRequestUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    }).done(function (response) {

        response.d.results.forEach(function (listItem) {

            if (listItem.Title === "domesticshipping") {
               $("#domesticShippingDays").text(listItem.c3t9 + " Business 
Days");
            }
            if (listItem.Title === "canadashipping") {
               $("#canadaShippingDays").text(listItem.c3t9 + " Business 
Days");
           }


        });
    }).fail(function () {
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong.");
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: When you say "Row 0 name: shipping", do you mean the value of the Title field for that row is "shipping"?

Comment: Correct. The very first column is the title row which is named shipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there are two parts to this:

1. Get the data from the SharePoint list
2. Put that data where you want it to go in your table

For retrieving the data from the list, I would recommend looking into using the REST API from Javascript code you put on the page where your table is, because then you will have the data in a place where you can easily then turn around and insert it into your table. I'm not going to go into too much detail here about how to do that, there are tons and tons of resources out there to help you figure it out (just google for "sharepoint rest api"), and the details of how that code would be written has entirely to do with which Javascript library you decide to use to help make the HTTP requests.  But for your example, you're probably going to want to put together a query like

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('CurrentTimeFrame')/items?$filter=Title eq 'shipping'&$select=Days
```

Now, for the second part, you are right that you'll have to add a little more HTML into your table, but I don't think you want to add `input`s.  An `input` will give you a text box that looks like you should be able to enter data into it.  You just need something to display the data in a read-only way (unless I'm completely misunderstanding what you are trying to do), so really all you need is an element that you can add an `id` to, so that you can find it from your Javascript code.  I would just add a `div` into your table cell:

```
<td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border-style:inset">
    <div id="shippingDays"></div>
</td>
```

Then when you get the data from the list, you can do

```
var shippingDaysDiv = document.getElementById("shippingDays");
shippingDaysDiv.innerText = retrievedDays + " Days";
```

As far as making sure the data in the table is refreshed, you won't really need to worry about that, because you'll set it up so the Javascript code runs every time the page is loaded, so anytime anyone goes to that page, they will always be seeing the newest data because the code dynamically goes out and retrieves the data from the list at that time.

---

In response to your question in the comments about which Javascript library to use, here are some suggestions:

One of the easiest to use, I think, is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).  You will definitely find plenty of examples of using jQuery's `$.ajax()` function to call SharePoint's REST API.  The downside is that you have to include the whole jQuery library just to be able to use `$.ajax()`.  That may or may not be a concern for you.  Also, you may end up having to use jQuery if you have to support Internet Explorer.  Oh, but an upside to using jQuery would be that you can use it to help you make inserting the data that you retrieve into the table a little easier, jQuery is very good for DOM manipulation.

If you don't have to support Internet Explorer, you could try using the native ES6 [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). `fetch()` is built-in to modern Javascript implementations (hence - not in IE), so you won't actually have to include an extra library.  If you're going to eventually be making SharePoint web parts using SPFx, I would go with `fetch()` because the tools provided in SPFx I believe are just wrappers for `fetch()`.  At least their syntax is very similar.

If you can get away with supporting only IE 11 from the IE family, another option to consider would be [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).  Axios syntax for *making* queries is very similar to jQuery `$.ajax()`, so it is pretty easy to understand, but the responses are a bit different, you just have to play around with it a little bit (and read the documentation) to see what's going on there and how to use it.

---

Based on your update with the code you have tried, here's what I see: a lot of room for improvement, which I can't fully get into here.  Sorry if that seems a little harsh, but it is the truth.  I'll throw out a brief list of some of the things I see that could improve, but I'm only going to get into the details of what needs to be improved in order to address the crux of your original question - how to get data from a list and insert it into a table.

1. Depending on how you are adding that HTML to a SharePoint page, you might not need the outer `<html>` tags or the `<head>` and `<body>` tags.  I would go so far as to say you most likely don't but the reasons for that are off topic here.
2. All your inline styles will be much easier to manage if you extract them into CSS classes and use classes on the table elements instead.
3. You are loading jQuery twice, which is unnecessary.  You first load version 1.4.2 from `jquery.com` and then you immediately override that by loading version 1.11.3 from `googleapis.com`, which means technically you have downgraded the version of jQuery you are using.  I know that SPServices has a *minimum* version of jQuery you need to use, but that does not mean you need to use *exactly* that version.  I would load the latest version of jQuery, and only do it once.
4. You are using SPServices.  There's nothing inherently wrong with SPServices, it's a very helpful library, but if you are on any version of SharePoint beyond 2010, it's probably easier to just query the REST API directly.  Even if you did still want to use SPServices, from the looks of your code, you have some problems with how you have that set up too.
5. From the looks of your code, it seems like you are trying to append rows to your table, instead of inserting the data directly into a table cell.  Not only that, it looks like you are trying to insert a two column row into a nine column table.

I would go back to what I had suggested before: setting yourself up with placeholder `div`s that have unique IDs that you can use to locate them later.  I am assuming the places you want to insert the data you get from the list are here

```
<td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border-style:inset">Domesticshipping &nbspBusiness Days</td>
```

and here

```
<td style="background-color:Black; color:White; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; border-style:inset">Canadashipping Business Days</td>
```

So here's how I would set up that row of the table.  I am omitting all the styling to make it a bit easier to see what's going on with the HTML itself:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">Domestic</td>
    <td><div id="domesticShippingDays"></div></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3">Canada</td>
    <td><div id="canadaShippingDays"></div></td>
</tr>
```

Then, in the script block I would do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // this tells jQuery to wait until the page has loaded before executing
    // the inner code.  this way we know the table has been rendered and we
    // will be able to find the placehoder divs
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // _spPageContextInfo is a built-in SharePoint javascript object
        // that has quite a bit of useful info.  in this case we're using
        // it to get the URL of the current site as the basis of the REST
        // query we will build.  as far as the REST query itself, it seems
        // that you do not want _only_ the row that has the domestic shipping
        // days, but you want the row that has the canada shipping days info
        // as well, so we are just going to go ahead and ask the list for _all_ items

        var timeFrameRequestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('CurrentTimeFrame')/items";

        // now we make the query
        $.ajax({
            url: timeFrameRequestUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            // the done function fires once the request succeeds
            // and the response has been received from the server.
            // since the query was for _all_ the list items, they
            // will be in an array called "results" that is on a property
            // called "d" which is part of the regular SharePoint REST response.
            response.d.results.forEach(function (listItem) {
                // we are iterating over each list item, so we can check to
                // see what the value of the Title field is, and take action accordingly
                if (listItem.Title === "domesticshipping") {
                    // here we grab the placeholder div by using it's ID
                    // and insert the text we want in it, including the number of days
                    // in the "days" column (internal name "c3t9")
                    $("#domesticShippingDays").text(listItem.c3t9 + " Business Days");
                }
                // you only showed a screenshot of what the domestic shipping
                // title column value is, so i'm just guessing at this. needless
                // to say, you should be checking for what the actual value is
                if (listItem.Title === "canadashipping") {
                    $("#canadaShippingDays").text(listItem.c3t9 + " Business Days");
                }
            });
        }).fail(function () {
            // the fail function will only fire if the request fails.
            // you can look up the documentation of this to see how you
            // can get more information about exactly what error occurred.
            alert("Oops! Something went wrong.");
        })
    })
</script>
```

I would also forewarn you that the weakness of this setup is that you are relying on the values of the Title fields, which can be easily edited and changed.  If someone at some point goes in to the `CurrentTimeFrame` list and changes "domesticshipping" to "Domestic Shipping", the code will break because

```
if (listItem.Title === "domesticshipping")
```

will never find the correct list item to get the days from.  Unless you go in and update your code to reflect the new field value like

```
if (listItem.Title === "Domestic Shipping")
```

As you can imagine, having to go in and update your code every time someone edits the Title of one of those list items will get annoying really quickly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the direction to go! I'll do some research into the REST API this weekend and give it a try!

Comment: Can you recommend a Javascript library that you like to use best? I was trained in C++, so I'm just learning java on my own. I don't know if there is a better library than another. Thanks again!

Comment: @mehumphry updated my answer with some suggestions.

Comment: That does help a lot! I do have to support IE, so I'll def look into JQuery. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I've tried to figure something out, but still can't quite get it. Can you possibly look at the new code entered above and see if you can point me in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong? I've tried to update the info in the post. I need to get the numerical value from the column 'days' (that has an internal name of 'c3t9').

Comment: @mehumphry updated my answer.

Comment: Ty so much for including the commentary on the code. That is what helps me learn most. I did update the code in the web snippet (and reflected in my question), but it still doesn't seem pull any values. I tried it both with calling jquery and without. Does the table need an id? I know this isn't the best setup, but I'm hoping to work on it after I have it functioning, and I take a couple classes as I don't think I'm going to be able to teach this language to myself. Is there anything apparent with the rewritten code as to why it might not be working? I'm sorry if I sound like a broken record!

Comment: Are you still pulling in at least one version of jQuery with a `<script src="//url/to/cdn"></script>` type line?  Originally you had two in a `<head>` section, and while you don't need the `<head>` tags themselves that define the head section, you _do_ need the `<script>` tags that link in the jQuery library.  In order to try and see what is happening, I would start with adding a line in the beginning of the `done` function, just before the `response.d.results.forEach` line, that is simply: `console.log(response);`.  Then open up the browser developer tools, and see what gets logged.

Comment: So there's two errors. 1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) and 2) Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. I think #2 is because I have the jquery script in the wrong place? I will move that to the top. #1 though, I found the link online to reference. Do you recommend a link to pull a version of jquery?

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU! I have it working now, and doing exactly what I need! Thank you for your patience and for explaining things to what probably seemed like a brick wall!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you managed to get it working!  And yes, you were right, the second error of `$ is not defined` is precisely because of the first error: using a CDN URL that was no longer valid (404 Not Found meant that the jQuery script file you were trying to pull in was not found at the address you specified in the `<script src="">`, therefore not pulling in jQuery.  You don't really have to worry about where on the page the `<script>` tag is that pulls jQuery, as long as it is _above_ the `<script>` block where you have `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it had to be at the top, but wasn't sure so that's where I ended up putting it. I'm still amazed by all of this!! Hahaha!

Comment: Houston, I have another problem! Came in this morning, everything seemed to work fine yesterday. It seems to be working on Edge but not Chrome this morning. Yesterday it worked on both. Chrome brings up the table, but no values in them. Only thing on the console is: [Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please usestart.js?rev=XFhC2yBo1NQ183GJoVt%2ByA%3D%3D:1 [Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.

Comment: Also just looked, when I go to edit the page, The script editor will show the table working with values. As soon as I hit save, they're all gone.

Comment: You could try making sure you have a `language` attribute and `type` attribute on _all_ your script tags, both the one that pulls in jQuery and the one for your script block.  `<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>`.  Other than that I'm not sure...

Comment: Didn't made any difference. So bizarre! Thank you for trying though!